# How can I serve multiple apps on different paths in an nx monorepo?

Tags: local, nx-monorepo

I have an nx monorepo with 5 apps. In production, these 5 apps are built and run on the same ngnix server under different paths. The apps use React router for inside navigation and with external links among each other when the user clicks on a different subpath.

Is it possible to serve the 5 apps locally (either on the same or on different ports) in a way that external links would work and I can navigate among the 5 apps?

I tried run-many and serving multiple apps seems to be working, but I can only access the routes of the first app I specify in the command line. I can also run the apps side-by-side on different ports, but I couldn't figure out how I can achieve cross-navigation.

Is there an existing solution to this?